# how to provide default value to a foreign while creating a new instance

Tags: python, django, model

i'm try to make a restaurant ordering system , when someone order multi products he/she be able to select the quantity of products which selected,
if all customers are anonymous(there is no registration option)

subquery in sql

i want to provide default value instead select manually

but i get this error

```
ValueError at /orders-product/
Cannot assign "4": "ProductOrder.order" must be a "Ordering" instance.
```

is there any solution , or if someone know a better way to achieve it, i appreciate it

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Ordering(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product,through='ProductOrder')

    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.productorder_set.aggregate(
            price_sum=Sum(F('quantity') * F('product__price'), output_field=IntegerField()) )['price_sum'] 


class ProductOrder(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Ordering, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

def create_order(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.ordering.save()
    #for create new instance from ordering model

pre_save.connect(create_order,sender=ProductOrder)
```

views.py

```
class ProductOrderCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = ProductOrdering
    model = ProductOrder
    template_name = 'create_product_order.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.order = list(Ordering.objects.values_list('pk' , flat=True).reverse().order_by('pk'))[0]
        return super(ProductOrderCreate,self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Step one would be correcting your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bunch of odd things in that `form_valid` method, but the error tells you what is specifically wrong, which is that you are using `values_list` to get a PK rather than passing the whole object.

Other things that are strange there are fetching everything by calling `list` on the queryset and then just getting the first; if you instead call `[0]` directly on the queryset that will translate to a LIMIT/OFFSET query to only fetch a single instance.

Also, you can reverse order by using `-` directly in the `order_by`.

```
form.instance.order = Ordering.objects.order_by('-pk')[0]
```